# Min and Max for vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, max, min

I'm creating a program need to filter only min log_time in Log_Type= I and max logtime in Log_Type = O. Need to display in reportviewer. Thanks guys i dont know how to start with in min and max

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the datasource of the reportviewer?

Comment: dataset sir mysql database.

Answer (score 2):

So you're using a `DataSet` as `DataSource` for the `ReportViewer` which is filled from a `MySql`-database. Then you should either filter the `DataSet`or filter via sql in the first place.

For example(via `Linq-To-DataSet`):

```
Dim groups = From row In ds.Tables(0)
             Let id = row.Field(Of Int32)("ID")
             Let empId = row.Field(Of String)("EMP_ID").Trim()
             Let logType = row.Field(Of String)("LOG_TYPE").Trim()
             Let logDate = row.Field(Of Date)("LOG_DATE")
             Let logTime = row.Field(Of TimeSpan)("LOG_TIME")
             Let creditDate = row.Field(Of Date)("CREDIT_DATE")
             Select data = New With {id, empId, logType, logDate, logTime, creditDate, row}
             Group data By data.empId, data.logType Into TypeGroup = Group

Dim newDataSource As DataTable = ds.Tables(0).Clone() ' empty table with same schema '
For Each grp In groups
    Dim iGroup = From data In grp.TypeGroup
                 Where StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals("i", data.logType)
    Dim min = (From data In iGroup Order By data.logTime Ascending).FirstOrDefault()
    Dim max = (From data In iGroup Order By data.logTime Descending).FirstOrDefault()
    If min IsNot Nothing Then
        newDataSource.Rows.Add(min.id, min.empId, min.logType, min.logDate, min.logTime, min.creditDate)
    End If
    If max IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not Object.ReferenceEquals(min, max) Then
        newDataSource.Rows.Add(max.id, max.empId, max.logType, max.logDate, max.logTime, max.creditDate)
    End If
    Dim oGroup = From data In grp.TypeGroup
                 Where StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals("o", data.logType)
    min = (From data In oGroup Order By data.logTime Ascending).FirstOrDefault()
    max = (From data In oGroup Order By data.logTime Descending).FirstOrDefault()
    If min IsNot Nothing Then
        newDataSource.Rows.Add(min.id, min.empId, min.logType, min.logDate, min.logTime, min.creditDate)
    End If
    If max IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not Object.ReferenceEquals(min, max) Then
        newDataSource.Rows.Add(max.id, max.empId, max.logType, max.logDate, max.logTime, max.creditDate)
    End If
Next

ds.Tables.Clear()
ds.Tables.Add(newDataSource)
```

Comment: Sir I declare ds as Dataset then i got this erro --Variable 'ds' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

Comment: sir another error @tim Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Renats: the code above compiles for me so i don't know what causes your error. You should mention at least the line where it occurs. Have you used the debugger to see what happens?

Comment: Dim groups = From row In ds.Tables(0) Let id = row.Field(Of Int32)("ID")
             Let empId = row.Field(Of String)("EMP_ID").Trim()
             Let logType = row.Field(Of String)("LOG_TYPE").Trim()
             Let logDate = row.Field(Of Date)("LOG_DATE")
             Let logTime = row.Field(Of TimeSpan)("LOG_TIME")
             Let creditDate = row.Field(Of Date)("CREDIT_DATE")
             Select data = New With {id, empId, logType, logDate, logTime, creditDate, row} Group data By data.empId, data.logType Into TypeGroup = Group

Comment: @Renats: so what is null, the dataset?

Comment: when i try your code sir . i dont know sir im a newbie in vb.net

Comment: sir @Tim Schmelter see the error above ..

Comment: Has Tim schmelter had a knighthood?

Comment: @Renats: the image has no debugger attached. You have to use it to find out which object is null. I assume it is the dataset itself.

Comment: i already use youre code sir @TimSchmelter but i dont know what to do sir please help me ..

Comment: sir @w0051977 help me .

Comment: @Renats: sorry, i have currently not the time to get a deeper insight. Maybe you could ask another question and provide all necessary informations, so that other people can help you.

Comment: okay sir thank you for the effort.

Comment: @TimSchmelter sir cannot find table 0 ?

Comment: @Renate: pardon? If your DataSet is empty I don't understand your requirements. Use the debugger if you don't know what's going.on.